# Add text to dates in material-calendarview

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm using this [material calendar view](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview). It looks very rich in customizable options.

But there is no example of **how to write text under day on certain dates.**

I think that I can use `DayViewDecorator` but how to do this with short string? I tried with:

```
    calendarView.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            view.addSpan(new SpannableString("ABC"));
        }
    });
```

Without success.

Answer (score 3):

@Thomas Banderas
it's just like when you use `dotspan` class. suppose you want to add price for each date then use this code below.

```
class AddTextToDates(text: String) : LineBackgroundSpan{

    private var dayPrice = text

    override fun drawBackground(
        canvas: Canvas,
        paint: Paint,
        left: Int,
        right: Int,
        top: Int,
        baseline: Int,
        bottom: Int,
        text: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        lnum: Int
    ) {
        canvas.drawText(dayPrice,((left+right)/4).toFloat(),(bottom+15).toFloat(),paint)
    }
}
```

In your decorator class inside `decorate`, function add the above class as span here is the full class.

```
class YourDecorator(dates: List<CalendarDay>,priceText:String) :DayViewDecorator {
    private val dates: HashSet<CalendarDay> = HashSet(dates)
    var priceDay = priceText

    override fun shouldDecorate(day: CalendarDay): Boolean {
        return dates.contains(day)
    }

    override fun decorate(view: DayViewFacade) {
        view.addSpan(AddTextToDates(priceDay))
        view.setDaysDisabled(true)
    }

}
```

for working example [browse](https://github.com/ELTEGANI/Android-CalendarView) this code and don't forget to star if it's useful for you. Hope it helps you guys :)

Comment: Thanks. It works. But how change the size of the text and set it to the center? )))

Comment: Sir glad it helps you. browse the docs you may find how to do it. if you find the answer useful please do vote for it.