# Labelling material-calendarview with Events

Tags: android, kotlin, calendarview

I'm trying to use [prolificinteractive's material-calendarview](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) to achieve something similar to the image I've attached, which has events added to the calendar. I'm thinking I could do this by creating a custom Span class as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008523/add-text-to-dates-in-material-calendarview) in another post.

However, my issue is that DayViewDecorator.decorate doesn't know which date it's currently decorating, so I can't pass specific event names to it. Is there a way I could achieve this using material-calendarview or are there other alternatives? Cheers

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7PH3.png)

**MainActivity.kt**
I thought decorate would be called after shouldDecorate, so I could define calendarDay in shouldDecorate, then call for its corresponding Event value in mapOfCalendarDays. But decorate is actually called first, and only once, before shouldDecorate is called for each day in the Calendar. This results in a crash, though, since calendarDay has not yet been initialized.

```
calendarView.addDecorator(object: DayViewDecorator {
    lateinit var calendarDay: CalendarDay

    override fun shouldDecorate(day: CalendarDay?): Boolean {
        return if (mapOfCalendarDays.containsKey(day)) { // check if 'day' is in mapOfCalendarDays (a map of CalendarDay to Event)
            calendarDay = day!!
            true
        } else false
    }

    override fun decorate(view: DayViewFacade?) {
        val event: Event? = mapOfCalendarDays[calendarDay]
        if (event != null) {
            view?.addSpan(AddTextToDates(event.name))
        }
    }
})
```

**Event.kt**

```
data class Event(
    val name: String,
    val date: LocalDate
)
```

**AddTextToDates.kt**

```
class AddTextToDates(text: String): LineBackgroundSpan {

    private val eventName = text

    override fun drawBackground(
        canvas: Canvas,
        paint: Paint,
        left: Int,
        right: Int,
        top: Int,
        baseline: Int,
        bottom: Int,
        text: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        lnum: Int
    ) {
        canvas.drawText(eventName, ((left+right)/4).toFloat(), (bottom+15).toFloat(), paint)
    }
}
```